# GMSMarker has no addGestureRecognizor?

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, uigesturerecognizer

How can I detect if a marker has been clicked on ?

here is my code :

```
 let Meridian = GMSMarker()
        Meridian.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 5.654874, longitude: 100.5320142)
        Meridian.title = "Recycling Factory"
        Meridian.snippet = "Meridian World Sdn Bhd"


        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.showMeridianInfo))
        Meridian.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)//here is where I get the error


  @objc func showMeridianInfo (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("meradin")


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to conform to `GMSMapViewDelegate` and implement the:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {}
```

within this function you have access to the selected marker details like title and etc.

```
marker.title
```